# Taylor series with less than differentiability

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, differential-operators, taylor-series

I have a function $f^0\colon (0;\infty) \to \mathbb R$ with the property that the following limit exists and is finite
$$
F^1 := \lim_{x\to \infty} x \cdot f^0(x)
$$
Then I consider $f^1(x) := x \cdot f^0(x) - F^1$ and let again the following limit exist:
$$
F^2 := \lim_{x\to \infty} x \cdot f^1(x)
$$
I continue with $f^2(x) := x \cdot f^1(x) - F^2$ and so on, such that I have for all $x \in (0;\infty)$
$$
f^0(x)
=
\frac 1 x F^1 + \frac 1 x f^1(x)
=
\frac 1 x F^1 + \frac 1 {x^2} F^2 + \frac 1 {x^2} f^2(x)
=
\ldots
=
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 {x^k} F^k + \frac 1 {x^n} f^n(x)
$$
which I can continue as long as the respective limits $F^k$ exist. Now I have something that reminds me of a Taylor expansion, where it is as if I take the respective derivatives in the point $\infty$.

Is there a theory on such series/polynoms and where can I read about it in order not to have to reinvent the wheel? Thank you!

EDIT: Change of variable $t = 1/x$ as proposed by a comment, i.e.
$$
g^0(t) :=
\begin{cases}
f^0(1/t), &t > 0, \\
0, &t = 0,
\end{cases}
$$
leads to equivalence of existence of $F^1$ and differentiability of $g$ in $0$. In that case, $g'(0) = F^1$. However, this is not true for higher orders since $g''(0)$ requires that $g'(t)$ exist for some $t>0$, whereas $F^2$ may exist without that condition (just multiply a smooth $f^0$ by an appropriate function that is nowhere differentiable).

Comment: Isn't it the Taylor expansion of $g(t)=f(1/t)$, $g(0)=0$?

Comment: This reminds me of [the principal part of a Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#Principal_part): you may find theorems on the representation of functions by Laurent series in almost every complex analysis textbooks. However, this is a bit out of topic in MathOverflow.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, not really because the second derivative $g''(0)$ would require the first derivative $g'(t)$ to exist on an open interval. However, we only know that $g'(0)$ exists.

Comment: We have $g′(0)=F^1$, but we do not necessarily have $g″(0)=2 F^2$, even if $g$ is $C^\infty$, I think. But I am also particularly interested in the cases where the derivatives do not exist for positive arguments.

Comment: In any case the change of variable $t=1/x$ translates the problem into polynomial expansions at $0$, for $g(t).$ One can do a calculus of polynomial expansions (without assuming $C^n$ regularity and without passing for Taylor expansions). For instance Peano did it somewhere.

Comment: @PietroMajer, thanks, but a quick search didn't help. If you point to a specific reference, that would be great. :)

Comment: A search on "Asymptotic Methods" or "Asymptotic Expansions" may be of interest for you (several textbooks do have the latter as a title indeed: by Erdélyi, by Copson, by Dingle,...)

Comment: Thank you, @PietroMajer, seems like at least the book of Copson is exactly what I was looking for!